# How do I install SQLObject for use with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlobject

I need to use SQLObject with Python and I downloaded SQLObject-1.0.0-py2.6.egg but I have no idea what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

For unix-type machines you should use easy_install (or better yet pip):

```
easy_install sqlobject
```

or

```
pip install sqlobject
```

(you might have to do this as root).

If you're using Windows you'll need to install either easy_install or pip.

You can get details on this at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows).

This will install SQLObject as well as any dependent libraries.

If you have the egg downloaded you can always:

```
easy_install /my_downloads/OtherPackage-3.2.1-py2.3.egg http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#downloading-and-installing-a-package (step four outlines this)
```

Again, you might have to be the superuser.